# 500W PSU made a loud bang while computer was off after being touched by screwdriver

Tags: power-supply, power

I was testing a PSU a friend loaned to me when troubleshooting a build. I put it in my PC, used it perfectly well, then shut it off. I was doing this to determine if a problem I was having was with the PSU or something else. It was something else.

I know it was foolish, but while I was trying to remove the PSU to put the old one back in, the screwdriver I was holding (plastic handle, fortunately) scraped along the PSU and went into a small vent hole in the bottom of it.

There was a loud bang, a flash, and a scorch mark on my screwdriver! It also blew the fuse in the mains cable (UK). I put the old power supply back in with a new cable and the computer worked fine, so I don't think it adversely affected the rest of my PC in any way.

What did I do? It looks like the screwdriver came into contact with a large sheet of metal - heatsink? - in the PSU, or possibly a large electrolytic 420uF capacitor, which would explain the sudden discharge. And also, is it safe to use that power supply again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have unloaded a static charge to your PSU which created a short circuit. (or shorted two components with the screwdriver)

If a "bang" has happened, you should avoid using that PSU, it's probably dead. Even if it still works somehow, it may be unstable (provide unproper voltage) and will damage the rest of your components which are way more expensive than a 500W PSU.

Answer (score 2):

There are capacitors in the PSU that hold charge for a fair while. Sounds like you shorted one.

No, I wouldn't use the PSU again. Something went bang, so it's broke

Rather than see it as a negative experience of losing your friend's PSU (hopefully not losing your friend), see it as a positive that you didn't electrocute yourself. Give yourself a treat. Relax tonight. It could have been much worse.

Comment: You're right. It was a spare, he won't mind. I am not dead. I will buy a new PSU and continue troubleshooting!

Answer (score 1):

> also blew the fuse in the mains cable (UK)

This doesn't sound like the result of a static charge.

I've read that shorting a capacitor is an acceptable way to safely drain it, so it probably wasn't just a capacitor on it's own.

I'd guess that you managed to **connect the main wall power to something** that overloaded & popped. Maybe a capacitor exploded because it wasn't meant to accept 110V or 220V (whatever the UK likes).

There's an easy way to find out exactly what's broken, if you're *extremely careful* this time and unplug the main power cord, and don't touch anything inside the power supply (like capacitors that may still hold a charge) you could take off the power supply's case and see what's black & ruined.

Comment: This would be more for curiosity than for any hope of salvaging it.

Comment: @SirAdelaide True, but it would answer the *"What did I do?"* question, and a solid yes or no to *"is it safe to use again?"* - If it's black and/or exploded, it's no longer safe.